# setting up a startup login password Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, login-manager

Currently when I login I do not have to provide a login password. I simply click on my user name and I get in. I would like to change that. In order to accomplish that I went to settings >> users  and then in Login options there was no password set next to the Password label. So I clicked on it and was prompted to enter my old password and new password. However after entering my new password the change button is still disabled. How can I enable that change button so that I could login using my password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `passwd` from the command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

It's a mechanism that prevents you to set a password that is too weak. Your password strength should be at least "Fair" in order to unlock the `Change` button.
Weak:

[image]

Fair:

[image]